# Is it possible to modify type definitions at runtime?

Tags: c++, types

Is it possible to modify type definitions at runtime? For example if you were to define a class like this

```
class Test {
   public:
       int x;
       int y;
};
```

could I remove the x or y field from the class at runtime? Or could I add more fields to this like adding a z field?

EDIT: This question is strictly out of curiosity.

Comment: No. As a strictly compiled language, once the source has passes through the compiler all types and variables are fixed.

Comment: And why are you asking? Is it only plain and simple curiosity? Then that's fine, but please state so in the question itself. Otherwise, if this is in regards to another problem that you try to solve, please ask about that problem directly instead. Since we don't know the original problem this question is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah just curiosity, updated my question to state that I am just curious. I always go back and forth on whether I should add information like that since it is not strictly part of the question but just my motivation. I agree it definitely makes a difference though because of people asking a generic question in leu of asking a specific question in regards to their problem.

Comment: In most scripted languages, you can modify structures at runtime. To achieve a similar functionality, you can use dynamic containers with keys and values, e.g. `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude literally an `x,y` problem in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is definitely impossible.

For example, we are updating the field x in the structure *Test* and **we must** know the size at the compile time because of operations on machine code level performs on data offsets

```cpp
class Test {
   public:
       int x;
       int y;
};


int main(){
    Test t;
    t.x = 10;
    return t.x - 1;
}
```

Expands to

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 10
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        sub     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

We are accessing the field x by direct writing the value into the address [rbp-8] (rbp holds the current frame pointer). We are subtracting 8 instead of adding because of the stack grows from the upper address to the lower.

But with C++ standard library and some masochistic tendencies you can write something like that (holding values in the variable 'values')

```cpp
#include <any>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Test {
   public:
       int x;
       int y;
};

int main(){
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::any> values;
    values.insert({"pi", 3.14f});
    values.insert({"test", Test{1,1}});

    std::cout<< std::any_cast<float>(values["pi"])<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::any_cast<Test>(values["test"]).x<<std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C++, by legacy from C, stores as little information as possible at run-time. For this reason, it does not support introspection and does not keep a run-time definition of the data types. On the opposite, the layout of structures is kept implicit, by having the correct offsets used in address computations. Thus the complete layout must be known at compile-time.

Answer (score -1):

No. You *can* do this at compile time, with some effort. C++ has `template`s. You can use a *template argument* to choose between different variants of `Test`, some with `x` and some with a `z`. But the template argument has to be a compile-time constant.  You cannot get it from `std::cin`.